# Excel Macro to group

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure if a macro would be the best solution to this problem, but I am looking to group rows and put in an if statement to make it a little easier.

I would like to see everything marked A to be grouped up into the above B. With the plus in the after table signifying the grouping plus that is added in Excel.

I tried formatting these as a table but ran into some issues I hope the way I broke up the text shows the main idea with the A's rolling up into the above B.

Before table:

```
B   88888   876  
A       8765  
A       8765  
A       8765  
B       
B   88888   8765  
A       5768  
A       8765  
B   88888   578  
A       578  
B       
B   88888   7658  
A       5768  
A       6578  
A       8765  
A       5768  
B   88888   5768  
A       5678
```

After table:

```
+   B   88888   876  
    B       
+   B   88888   8765  
+   B   88888   578  
    B       
+   B   88888   7658  
+   B   88888   5768
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will group all rows staring with "A..."

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub customGroups()
    Const FR As Long = 2    'first row (exclude header)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, grp As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        With .UsedRange
            .Rows.ClearOutline
            Set ur = .Offset(FR - 1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - (FR - 1), .Columns.Count)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=A*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            For Each grp In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
                If grp.Row > FR - 1 Then grp.Rows.Group
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Outline
            .ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
            .SummaryRow = xlAbove
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

.

[image]

Comment: One problem I have noticed though is when I add more rows and re run the macro to group those rows it creates additional groupings. I did kind of make a way to combat this by recording a macro selecting all and then ungrouping so I just run that before I run your macro to group the data.

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding .Rows.ClearOutline (after With .UsedRange). See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Is every group separated by a blank row in your actual data?

And I assume you've changed your grouping settings to have the expansion on top?  Otherwise for starters:
[Data]-->In the Grouping Ribbon there is a little box in the bottom right. Click it for [Settings].  Uncheck the box that says [Summary rows below detail].